# Campaignresponse entity create in plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I wrote plugin that fire on phonecall step is setstatedynamic.
I register post image in step my plugin.I get phonecall entity from postimage.
And When i set phonecallid  to origanitingactivityid on campaign response

```
(
like

campaignResponse.OriginatingActivityId = new EntityReference();
campaignResponse.OriginatingActivityId.LogicalName = PhoneCall.EntityLogicalName;
campaignResponse.OriginatingActivityId.Id = phoneCall.ActivityId.Value;
)
```

Plugin throws timeout.(I set serviceproxy,Timeout property 30 minutes,its still throw timeout.)
When i dont set originatingactivityid,campaingresponse is created.

Any suggestion about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
campaignResponse.OriginatingActivityId = new EntityReference(PhoneCall.EntityLogicalName, phoneCall.Id);
```

this works for me.

Comment: this is really interesting. I just tested this on two CRM instances. One working great, other throws same exception :)
I'll take some time to investigate this

Comment: I found this problem,ActivityPointerBase table's indexs fragmented,i made rebuild all.Now its working.